# Connecting Windows Azure to On-Premise Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect my Windows Azure Virtual machines to my On Premise network. I have established a site to site VPN tunnel, and have created the appropriate subnets and placed a virtual machine in one of the subnets that isn't the gateway subnet.

My on premise test network is 192.168.9.x/24 my Azure Network is 10.4.x.x/16 with a subnet for DMZ - 10.4.2.x/24 and ServerNetwork at 10.4.3.x/24.

I have confirmed that the tunnel is up and running both on the Windows Azure side, as well as on my Cisco ASA 5505.

I want my servers to be able to communicate across the tunnel, however currently they cannot see each other. I am missing something, I tried static routes between the two servers, and have not had any success. Has anyone gotten this to work? If so what did you do on the networking side of the config to make it work?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure Virtual Network enables you to create secure site-to-site connectivity, as well as protected private virtual networks in the cloud.

You can specify the address space that will be used for both your virtual network and the virtual network gateway.

Additionally, new name resolution features allow you to connect directly to role instances and virtual machines by hostname.

These features allow you to use Windows Azure as you would a branch office, or as a protected private virtual network in the cloud.

You can read more about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156007.aspx

Here is a lab exercise to walk you through the process:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/create-a-virtual-network/